# Aggregate query on 50M+ row table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, aggregate

## Problem statement

I have table "event_statistics" with following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE public.event_statistics (
    id int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('event_statistics_id_seq'::regclass),
    client_id int4 NULL,
    session_id int4 NULL,
    action_name text NULL,
    value text NULL,
    product_id int8 NULL,
    product_options jsonb NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb,
    url text NULL,
    url_options jsonb NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb,
    visit int4 NULL DEFAULT 0,
    date_update timestamptz NULL,
CONSTRAINT event_statistics_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT event_statistics_client_id_session_id_sessions_client_id_id_for 
FOREIGN KEY 
(client_id,session_id) REFERENCES <?>() ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
) ;
CREATE INDEX regdate ON public.event_statistics (date_update 
timestamptz_ops) ;
```

And table "clients":

```
CREATE TABLE public.clients (
    id int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('clients_id_seq'::regclass),
    client_name text NULL,
    client_hash text NULL,
CONSTRAINT clients_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
) ;
CREATE INDEX clients_client_name_idx ON public.clients (client_name 
text_ops) ;
```

What I need is to get count of events in "event_statistics" table of each "action_name" type for specific "date_update" range grouping by "action_name" and specific time step and all of that for specific client.

The goal is to provide statistics for all relevant events for each client on his dashboard on our web site with option to choose report dates and depending on interval time step in chart should be different like:

- current day — count for each hour;
- 1+ day and <= 1 month — count for each day;
- 1+ month and <= 6 months — count for each week;
- 6+ months — month.

## What I did:

```
SELECT t.date, A.actionName, count(E.id)
FROM generate_series(current_date - interval '1 week',now(),interval '1 
day') as t(date) cross join
(values
('page_open'),
('product_add'),
('product_buy'),
('product_event'),
('product_favourite'),
('product_open'),
('product_share'),
('session_start')) as A(actionName) left join
(select action_name,date_trunc('day',e.date_update) as dateTime, e.id 
from event_statistics as e 
where e.client_id = (select id from clients as c where c.client_name = 
'client name') and 
(date_update between (current_date - interval '1 week') and now())) E 
on t.date = E.dateTime and A.actionName = E.action_name
group by A.actionName,t.date
order by A.actionName,t.date;
```

It takes too long, more than 10 seconds, to count events by event type and day for last week. I need it to be able to do the same faster and for wider periods of time like weeks, months, years with different group interval(each hour of current day, days for month, then weeks, months).

The query plan:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=171937.16..188106.84 rows=1600 width=44)
  Group Key: "*VALUES*".column1, t.date
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Seq Scan on clients c  (cost=0.00..1.07 rows=1 width=4)
          Filter: (client_name = 'client name'::text)
  ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=171936.08..183784.31 rows=574060 width=44)
        Merge Cond: (("*VALUES*".column1 = e.action_name) AND (t.date =(date_trunc('day'::text, e.date_update))))
        ->  Sort  (cost=628.77..648.77 rows=8000 width=40)
              Sort Key: "*VALUES*".column1, t.date
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.02..110.14 rows=8000 width=40)
                    ->  Function Scan on generate_series t (cost=0.02..10.02 rows=1000 width=8)
                    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..0.14 rows=8 width=32)
                          ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.10 rows=8 width=32)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=171307.32..171881.38 rows=114812 width=24)
              ->  Sort  (cost=171307.32..171594.35 rows=114812 width=24)
                    Sort Key: e.action_name, (date_trunc('day'::text, e.date_update))
                    ->  Index Scan using regdate on event_statistics e (cost=0.57..159302.49 rows=114812 width=24)
                          Index Cond: ((date_update > (('now'::cstring)::date - '7 days'::interval)) AND (date_update <= now()))
                          Filter: (client_id = $0)
```

The "event_statistics" table has more than 50 millions of rows and it will only grow with clients added and the records will not be changed.

I've tried a lot of different query plans and indexes but couldn't reach acceptable speed when aggregated for wider date range.
I've spent whole week learning different aspects of this problem and ways to solve this on stackoverflow and some blogs, but still unsure what is the best way:

- partitioning by client_id or date range
- pre-aggregate to separate result table and then update it on a daily basis(also not sure how to do it best? trigger on insert into original table or schedule a separate app for that or materialized view or by a request from the web site)
- change DB schema design to schema per client or apply sharding
- change server hardware(CPU Intel Xeon E7-4850 2.00GHz, RAM 6GB and it's the host of both web app and the DB)
- use a different DB for analytics with OLAP capabilities like Postgres-XL 
  or something else?

I also tried btree index on event_statistics (client_id asc, action_name asc, date_update asc, id). And it was faster with index only scan, but still not enough and it's not very good in terms of disk space usage.

**What is the best way to solve this problem?**

## Update

As requested, the output of `explain (analyze, verbose)` command:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=860934.44..969228.46 rows=1600 width=44) (actual time=52388.678..54671.187 rows=64 loops=1)
  Output: t.date, "*VALUES*".column1, count(e.id)
  Group Key: "*VALUES*".column1, t.date
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Seq Scan on public.clients c  (cost=0.00..1.07 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.058..0.059 rows=1 loops=1)
          Output: c.id
          Filter: (c.client_name = 'client name'::text)
          Rows Removed by Filter: 5
  ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=860933.36..940229.77 rows=3864215 width=44) (actual time=52388.649..54388.698 rows=799737 loops=1)
        Output: t.date, "*VALUES*".column1, e.id
        Merge Cond: (("*VALUES*".column1 = e.action_name) AND (t.date = (date_trunc('day'::text, e.date_update))))
        ->  Sort  (cost=628.77..648.77 rows=8000 width=40) (actual time=0.190..0.244 rows=64 loops=1)
              Output: t.date, "*VALUES*".column1
              Sort Key: "*VALUES*".column1, t.date
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 30kB
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.02..110.14 rows=8000 width=40) (actual time=0.059..0.080 rows=64 loops=1)
                    Output: t.date, "*VALUES*".column1
                    ->  Function Scan on pg_catalog.generate_series t  (cost=0.02..10.02 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.043..0.043 rows=8 loops=1)
                          Output: t.date
                          Function Call: generate_series(((('now'::cstring)::date - '7 days'::interval))::timestamp with time zone, now(), '1 day'::interval)
                    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..0.14 rows=8 width=32) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=8 loops=8)
                          Output: "*VALUES*".column1
                          ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.10 rows=8 width=32) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=8 loops=1)
                                Output: "*VALUES*".column1
        ->  Materialize  (cost=860304.60..864168.81 rows=772843 width=24) (actual time=52388.441..54053.748 rows=799720 loops=1)
              Output: e.id, e.date_update, e.action_name, (date_trunc('day'::text, e.date_update))
              ->  Sort  (cost=860304.60..862236.70 rows=772843 width=24) (actual time=52388.432..53703.531 rows=799720 loops=1)
                    Output: e.id, e.date_update, e.action_name, (date_trunc('day'::text, e.date_update))
                    Sort Key: e.action_name, (date_trunc('day'::text, e.date_update))
                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 39080kB
                    ->  Index Scan using regdate on public.event_statistics e  (cost=0.57..753018.26 rows=772843 width=24) (actual time=31.423..44284.363 rows=799720 loops=1)
                          Output: e.id, e.date_update, e.action_name, date_trunc('day'::text, e.date_update)
                          Index Cond: ((e.date_update >= (('now'::cstring)::date - '7 days'::interval)) AND (e.date_update <= now()))
                          Filter: (e.client_id = $0)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 2983424
Planning time: 7.278 ms
Execution time: 54708.041 ms
```

Comment: The pain appears to be in the sorting  on the low-cardinality text column action_name. (personally, I'd prefer  a numeric action_id here) Also: the the (func) calendartable and the (values) action_name preudo-tables both dont have usable hooks for optimisation (indexes,statistics),I'd materialise them into (TEMP) tables

Comment: Thank you for the hints. Yes, the problem seems to be in the slow external disk sorting and reading through data for all clients. But for some reason I couldn't eliminate the need for sorting even with a covering index like I wrote in the end of the post. It's much faster with such an index only when I sufficiently increased "work_mem" and in-memory sort was used but still not enough because of slow reading "event_statistics" table.

Comment: IMO you can pre-aggregate in the sub query. It wont yield more than 1600 aggregates.

Comment: The outer query yields 1600 aggregates. (distinct id) and has exactly the same grouping columns (day, action_name)

Comment: Could you give an example how exactly to pre-aggregate, please? Maybe in an answer post if you think it may solve my problem. And why 1600? The query plan is for the example query which aggregates only for 1 week that is not a problem. The problem is doing the same for months or years.

Comment: Could you upload the table data on some paltform like zippyshare? Of course, any identifying info should be removed first by making a copy of the tables and dropping such columns. That would hide issues due to size of data (like long TEXT/jsonb columns) but it would give the right distribution for all the rest.

Comment: `Function Scan on generate_series t (cost=0.02..10.02 rows=1000 width=8)` 1000 is the default estimate for generate_series(). And in this case is is too large... Maybe materialising (+analyze) the calendar file could hint the optimiser.

Comment: `The problem is doing the same for months or years` These are different queries, which might be optimised differently. Firs ttep would be to materialize the generate_series() result, to get some meaningful statistics.(although the 1000 estimate could be a nice fit;-)

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. (note the `analyze` option!)

Answer (score 1):

First step: perform pre-aggregation in the subquery:

---

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT cal.theday, act.action_name, SUM(sub.the_count)
FROM generate_series(current_date - interval '1 week', now(), interval '1 
day') as cal(theday) -- calendar pseudo-table
CROSS JOIN (VALUES
        ('page_open')
        , ('product_add') , ('product_buy') , ('product_event')
        , ('product_favourite') , ('product_open') , ('product_share') , ('session_start')
        ) AS act(action_name)
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT es.action_name, date_trunc('day',es.date_update) as theday
                , COUNT(DISTINCT es.id ) AS the_count
        FROM event_statistics as es
        WHERE es.client_id = (SELECT c.id FROM clients AS c
                        WHERE c.client_name = 'client name')
        AND (es.date_update BETWEEN (current_date - interval '1 week') AND now())
        GROUP BY 1,2
        ) sub ON cal.theday = sub.theday AND act.action_name = sub.action_name
GROUP BY act.action_name,cal.theday
ORDER BY act.action_name,cal.theday
        ;
```

---

Next step:put VALUES into a CTE and refer to it also in the aggregate subquery.
(the gain depends on the number of action names that can be skipped)

---

```
EXPLAIN
WITH act(action_name) AS (VALUES
        ('page_open')
        , ('product_add') , ('product_buy') , ('product_event')
        , ('product_favourite') , ('product_open') , ('product_share') , ('session_start')
        )
SELECT cal.theday, act.action_name, SUM(sub.the_count)
FROM generate_series(current_date - interval '1 week', now(), interval '1day') AS cal(theday)
CROSS JOIN act
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT es.action_name, date_trunc('day',es.date_update) AS theday
                , COUNT(DISTINCT es.id ) AS the_count
        FROM event_statistics AS es
        WHERE es.date_update BETWEEN (current_date - interval '1 week') AND now()
        AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM clients cli  WHERE cli.id= es.client_id AND cli.client_name = 'client name')
        AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM act WHERE act.action_name = es.action_name)
        GROUP BY 1,2
        ) sub ON cal.theday = sub.theday AND act.action_name = sub.action_name
GROUP BY act.action_name,cal.theday
ORDER BY act.action_name,cal.theday
        ;
```

---

UPDATE: using a fysical (temp) table will result in better estimates.

---

```
    -- Final attempt: materialize the carthesian product (timeseries*action_name)
    -- into a temp table
CREATE TEMP TABLE grid AS
(SELECT act.action_name, cal.theday
FROM generate_series(current_date - interval '1 week', now(), interval '1 day')
    AS cal(theday)
CROSS JOIN
    (VALUES ('page_open')
        , ('product_add') , ('product_buy') , ('product_event')
        , ('product_favourite') , ('product_open') , ('product_share') , ('session_start')
        ) act(action_name)
    );
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON grid(action_name, theday);

    -- Index will force statistics to be collected
    -- ,and will generate better estimates for the numbers of rows
CREATE INDEX iii ON event_statistics (action_name, date_update ) ;
VACUUM ANALYZE grid;
VACUUM ANALYZE event_statistics;

EXPLAIN
SELECT grid.action_name, grid.theday, SUM(sub.the_count) AS the_count
FROM grid
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT es.action_name, date_trunc('day',es.date_update) AS theday
                , COUNT(*) AS the_count
        FROM event_statistics AS es
        WHERE es.date_update BETWEEN (current_date - interval '1 week') AND now()
        AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM clients cli  WHERE cli.id= es.client_id AND cli.client_name = 'client name')
        -- AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM grid WHERE grid.action_name = es.action_name)
        GROUP BY 1,2
        ORDER BY 1,2 --nonsense!
        ) sub ON grid.theday = sub.theday AND grid.action_name = sub.action_name
GROUP BY grid.action_name,grid.theday
ORDER BY grid.action_name,grid.theday
        ;
```

---

Update#3 (sorry, I create indexes on the base table(s)here, You'll need to edit. I also removed the one-columns onthetimestamp)

---

```
    -- attempt#4:
    -- - materialize the carthesian product (timeseries*action_name)
    -- - sanitize date interval -logic

CREATE TEMP TABLE grid AS
(SELECT act.action_name, cal.theday::date
FROM generate_series(current_date - interval '1 week', now(), interval '1 day')
    AS cal(theday)
CROSS JOIN
    (VALUES ('page_open')
        , ('product_add') , ('product_buy') , ('product_event')
        , ('product_favourite') , ('product_open') , ('product_share') , ('session_start')
        ) act(action_name)
    );

    -- Index will force statistics to be collected
    -- ,and will generate better estimates for the numbers of rows
-- CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON grid(action_name, theday);
-- CREATE INDEX iii ON event_statistics (action_name, date_update ) ;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON grid(theday, action_name);
CREATE INDEX iii ON event_statistics (date_update, action_name) ;
VACUUM ANALYZE grid;
VACUUM ANALYZE event_statistics;

EXPLAIN
SELECT gr.action_name, gr.theday
            , COUNT(*) AS the_count
FROM grid gr
LEFT JOIN event_statistics AS es
    ON es.action_name = gr.action_name
    AND date_trunc('day',es.date_update)::date = gr.theday
    AND es.date_update BETWEEN (current_date - interval '1 week') AND current_date
JOIN clients cli  ON cli.id= es.client_id AND cli.client_name = 'client name'
GROUP BY gr.action_name,gr.theday
ORDER BY 1,2
        ;
```

---

```
                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                        
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=8.33..8.35 rows=1 width=17)
   Group Key: gr.action_name, gr.theday
   ->  Sort  (cost=8.33..8.34 rows=1 width=17)
         Sort Key: gr.action_name, gr.theday
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.40..8.33 rows=1 width=17)
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.31..7.78 rows=1 width=40)
                     Join Filter: (es.client_id = cli.id)
                     ->  Index Scan using clients_client_name_key on clients cli  (cost=0.09..2.30 rows=1 width=4)
                           Index Cond: (client_name = 'client name'::text)
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on event_statistics es  (cost=1.22..5.45 rows=5 width=44)
                           Recheck Cond: ((date_update >= (('now'::cstring)::date - '7 days'::interval)) AND (date_update <= ('now'::cstring)::date))
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on iii  (cost=0.00..1.22 rows=5 width=0)
                                 Index Cond: ((date_update >= (('now'::cstring)::date - '7 days'::interval)) AND (date_update <= ('now'::cstring)::date))
               ->  Index Only Scan using grid_theday_action_name_idx on grid gr  (cost=0.09..0.54 rows=1 width=17)
                     Index Cond: ((theday = (date_trunc('day'::text, es.date_update))::date) AND (action_name = es.action_name))
(15 rows)
```

Comment: I tested your solution and checked the query plan. Thank you for the efforts, but unfortunately the query you proposed performs even a little slower (+1-2 sec.) than mine because it does more checks and joins. I can't benefit from the filter on "action_name" because I need to aggregate for all of them that may be in the "event_statistics" table and I listed them manually as VALUES because fetching distinct "action_name" values from the table is very very slow.

Comment: Try replacing action_name by a numerical `action_id integer not null FOREIGN KEY referencing action_name id)` , with action_names {id,action_name} as a dimension table. And add some usable (composite) indexes.

Comment: Still slow. The indexed temp table helps a bit when there is a lot of combinations of timestamps and action names, but under current conditions doesn't make a difference. Otherwise I would do it. And the index on (action_name, date_update) I tried earlier also, but it didn't help, although I applied "vacuum analyze". The optimizer almost always chooses seq. scan over this index.

Comment: You appear to have a data-modelling problem with this *fact table* :too many key-elements (low cardinality), and too many (almost) candidate-keys. Also:there is a lot of *meat on the bones* (text,json,...) but that will probably be toasted anyway. I have one more candidate(basically reforming the timestamp->datepart manipulations), which creates good plans here... BRB ...