# How to add rows which have 0 count in table using in psql query and typeorm query

Tags: node.js, database, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I've one query which lists data which was present only at that date, for example -> In range of dates if no data present at 2021-05-13, So using that query i got no row for that date, but i need that row with count 0.

query in psql -

```
select date_trunc('day', e."createdAt") as production_to_month, count(id) as count from events e 
where e."createdAt" between '2021-05-10' and '2021-05-17' and e."type" = 'LOGIN'
group by date_trunc('day', e."createdAt") 
order by date_trunc('day', e."createdAt") asc
```

query in typeorm -

```
return await getRepository(Events)
  .createQueryBuilder("e")
  .select("date_trunc('day',`e`.`createdAt`)","production_to_month")
  .addSelect("count(`id`)","count")
  .where("`e`.`createdAt` between '2021-05-10' and '2021-05-17'")
  .andWhere("`e`.`type` = 'LOGIN'")
  .groupBy("date_trunc('day',`e`.`createdAt`)").
  .orderBy("date_trunc('day',`e`.`createdAt`)","ASC")
  .printSql()
  .getRawMany()
```

Comment: You;ll need a `calendar table`, and left join to it.

Comment: Hi @wildplasser, you mean to say i've to make new calender table. Can you please send me the query in typeorm or in postgres form. Thanks!

Comment: Can be done with `generate_series('2021-05-10' , '2021-05-17' , '1day'::interval)` See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45906851/905902